# Proper way to consume and immediately publish RabbitMQ messages from queue-to-queue?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, rabbitmq, windows-services

What is the proper method of consuming a message, processing it, and then publishing it? I run into a lot of unacknowledged messages and I believe there is some blocking going on. Trying to understand the best practice for something like this.

I'm working on a set of services that will process around 50k requests a day. I have decided to use RabbitMQ and three Windows Services written in Dotnet Core 3.1.

I have diagrammed the process but essentially it works like this:

- an external service publishes the message to Queue #1
- service A is "listening" on Queue #1 and consumes any messages that arrive in the Queue. A database call is made and then Service A passes message to Queue #2
- service B is "listening" on Queue #2 and consumes any messages that arrive in the Queue. Some internal processing is done and then Service B passes message to Queue #3
- service C is "listening" on Queue #2 and consumes any messages that arrive in the Queue. Some internal processing is done and then Service C pushes message to database

Code example is below image

[image]

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        logger.LogInformation("Starting Service ...");

        base.OnStart(args);
        string queue = "Queue_StageOne";

        this.connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        this.channel = connection.CreateModel();
        this.publishingChannel = connection.CreateModel();
        this.channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);

        consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        consumer.Received += Consumer_Recieved;

        this.channel.BasicConsume(queue: queue, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);
    }

    private async Task Consumer_Recieved(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs @event)
    {
        var body = @event.Body;
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body.ToArray());
        var inboundTransferObject = PatientObject.ConvertFromJson(message);

        //logger.LogInformation("Processed message " + inboundTransferObject.WebhookMessageId);

        //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault;
        //X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(config["CertificationPath"].ToString(), config["PFXPassword"]);

        //JToken access_token = GetAccessToken(cert);

        //JObject payerData = GetPractitionerData(inboundTransferObject, cert, access_token);

        //inboundTransferObject = ProcessPractitioner(inboundTransferObject, payerData);

        var outboundTransferObject = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inboundTransferObject.ConvertToJson());

        channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: @event.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
        publishingChannel.BasicPublish(exchange: "ExchangeA", routingKey: "Queue_StageTwo", basicProperties: null, body:outboundTransferObject);
        await Task.Delay(250);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're asking here but one thing that does stand out is that your services should not acknowledge the inbound message unless and until they've completed all their processing steps, and that includes publishing follow-on outbound messages. In your code sample you appear to acknowledge the inbound message *before* publishing the outbound message.

That however does not explain the symptom you described "I run into a lot of unacknowledged messages". When do you run into these? How many is a lot? Have you set a prefetch limit on your channel? For testing purposes, you could try setting your prefetch count to one to ensure that only one message is in-flight at a time.

`channel.BasicQos(1, global: true)`

Please see [this section](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#channel-qos-prefetch) of the RabbitMQ documentation:

> *"Because messages are sent (pushed) to clients asynchronously, there is usually more than one message "in flight" on a channel at any given moment. In addition, manual acknowledgements from clients are also inherently asynchronous in nature. So there's a sliding window of delivery tags that are unacknowledged. Developers would often prefer to cap the size of this window to avoid the unbounded buffer problem on the consumer end. This is done by setting a "prefetch count" value using the basic.qos method. The value defines the max number of unacknowledged deliveries that are permitted on a channel. Once the number reaches the configured count, RabbitMQ will stop delivering more me*ssages on the channel unless at least one of the outstanding ones is acknowledged."

Comment: Note that one is rarely the optimal pre-fetch count. It's usually necessary to tweak this number for best throughput.

Comment: Thanks for response. I do have it set to prefetch one message at a time. I was not clear in my description the unacknowledged messages - what happens is a message from queue 1 is moved to queue 2 and at that point it becomes unacknowledged. When you say that I appear to acknowledge the inbound message before publishing it - perhaps my understanding is off but the line of thinking that I was working under is that the message is consumed, then acknowledged, some processing is done and then its published. I see what you are saying about acking after publish and will give that a try